# jstl c:import causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Should never reach here

Tags: jsp, import, jstl, glassfish-4.1

I have a page with this code:

```
<c:import var="content" url="/assets/template/login.jsp" context="/externalcontext"/>
${content}
```

In the first request, I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Should never reach here`. If I do the request again, the erro doesn't happens anymore.
Tracking the code, I found something related to the `org.apache.catalina.connector.SessionTracker`. It seems like that in first request, the session isn't tracked yet. In the next request, this error doesn't happens.

I am using Glassfish v4.1.1.

Comment: ${content} seems misplaced. It should be inside a tag (e.g. <c:out value="${content}"/>

Comment: @dsp_user: that's only true if you're using the jurassic JSP 1.x.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that correction.

Comment: BTW, since c:import is using an absolute url , you may try to change it to something like gttp://assets/templates/login.jsp . I know I've had this exception because of the incorrect syntax in some of the attributes (though not with c:import)

Comment: @dsp_user when I use the 'complete' URL, it works. But I need that the request pass by some application interceptors to some object as attributes. It seems something related to session creation between 'main' application and the 'external' application.